# Wi Fi limited to 1M. Bit rate cannot be set

Tags: networking, drivers

A few days ago, I upgraded the kernel to 4.5.2 (I run Ubuntu Mate 14.04 LTS) and my ASUS USB-N13 Wi-Fi dongle now isn't working properly.

I tried to add in:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

These lines:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 0
```

And after in a terminal I entered:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo iwconfig
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
```

But it remains on 1M with the error `Cannot set bit rate`.

```
Error for wireless request "Set Bit Rate" (8B20) :
    SET failed on device wlan0
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issues with unsupported kernels are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add the line: `wireless-rate 54M`

Restart. It could work, sometimes your adapter doesn't take this configuration, so you can try this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

This will open your Wifi connection configuration, then add the following after "mode":

`rate=Auto`  or `rate=54M`